# Both optIn and login is not working in onesignal_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, flutter-dependencies, onesignal

Has anyone implemented the functionality of toggling between Opt-In and Opt-Out, as well as logging in using **onesignal_flutter**?

I'm trying to do it, but only one of these is working. I mean, if I have (or called) both functions, either of the functions is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Anyone from the team or other developers who know about it, please reply to me. I've been struggling a lot for the past three days to crack this.

handleLogin function :

```
 Future<void> handleLogin() async {
    String? externalUserId = ''.generateUuid();

    final GetUserModel currentUser = cacheManager.getNewUser();
    String? userId = currentUser.userInfoData!.userInfoId!;

    await OneSignal.login(externalUserId);
    await OneSignal.User.addAlias("user_id", userId);
  }
```

handleOptIn function :

```
  Future<void> handleOptIn() async {
    await OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optIn();
  }
```

handleOptOut function :

```
  Future<void> handleOptOut() async {
    await OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issues.

Comment: I have raised this issue on GitHub and OneSignal Team is working on this issue. You can check in the following link.

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/811